# jQuery disable/re-enable validators on a page

Tags: asp.net, jquery

When I need to disable/re-enable validator I usually use jQuery code like so:

```
      ValidatorEnable($('[id*=DueDateRequiredValidator]')[0], false);
```

and to re-enable it back:

```
      ValidatorEnable($('[id*=DueDateRequiredValidator]')[0], true);
            var validator = $('[id*=DueDateRequiredValidator]')[0];
            validator.isvalid = true;
            ValidatorUpdateDisplay(validator);
```

And it works. But now I need to disable/re-enable a large number of validators, but only a subset of validators, not entire set on a page. There's too many of them to refer each validator by "id".

I tried something like this but it didn't work, don't know why:

```
      $.each(Page_Validators, function(index, validator) {
                if ( validator.CssClass == "noinjuries" )

                { ValidatorEnable(validator, false); } 


      });
```

What's the best way to do this, if any?

Comment: I was looking for the jquery validator enable and this helped.. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, try this first

`if ($(validator).hasClass('noinjuries')) { /* disable validator */ }`

Comment: Yes, it works, and it's better suited for what I am doing as my validators might have multiple classes

Answer (score 0):

I found the following javascript code [on a blog](http://veskokolev.blogspot.com/2007/11/how-to-disable-validation-group-with.html), it uses a ValidationGroup to toggle Validation controls, but you could just as easily remove the `if (Page_Validators[i].validationGroup == validationGroupName)` line and toggle the whole collection of Validators.

You will have to add your own enabling code after the 'ValidatorEnable' method call.

```
function HasPageValidators() {
    var hasValidators = false;

    try {
        if (Page_Validators.length > 0) {
            hasValidators = true;
        }
    }
    catch (error) {
    }

    return hasValidators;
}

function ValidationGroupEnable(validationGroupName, isEnable) {
    if (HasPageValidators()) {
        for (i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++) {
            if (Page_Validators[i].validationGroup == validationGroupName) {
                ValidatorEnable($('[id*=DueDateRequiredValidator]')[0], true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Edit:** Victor, based on your comment, I think you could get the same results by adding Attributes to your controls. This would group them without using the ValidationGroups, and you can access the attributes from JavaScript.

In your code behind, you need to set the attributes for your Validation controls like so:

```
SampleValidator1.Attributes.Add("myGroupName", "sample1");
SampleValidator2.Attributes.Add("myGroupName", "sample2");
```

Then, in the Javascript function, rather than this line `if (Page_Validators[i].validationGroup == validationGroupName) {', use this:

```
if (Page_Validators[i].getAttribute('myClass') == 'sample1') {
```

That should get you what you want without Groups, but sorry - you will have to set the Attribute

---

**One Last Edit:** I was making this harder than it needs to be. I haven't tried it, but if you want to get the CSS class of an object in JavaScript it is `.className`, not `.class`. Try that before any of my earlier suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Problem is I can't use ValidationGroups on parts of my page since it will cause incorrect behavior of a page as a whole. Is there any way to use `class` for example instead, i.e. replace this condition `if (Page_Validators[i].validationGroup == validationGroupName)` with this `if (Page_Validators[i].class == classGroupName)`?

Comment: I made two edits, and now you should have a better answer. Good luck.